# Why are the spaces in the RDF syntax appearing as %20 (Ontotext Refine and GraphDB)?

Tags: rdf, graphdb, openrefine

I am a beginner to RDFs and I'm creating triples of the data with Ontotext Refine. I'm using the community edition of Ontotext GraphDB for viewing graphs. I created a RDF triple from the Fortune 500 dataset in the following

[image]

When I click the 'Open in GraphDB' button and run the SPARQL query generated, it returns the following result

[image]

Why is the prefix value not working, and showing the URL instead of the variable? Also, the URL code for the space is visible in the 7th and 8th row. The URL codes for ',' and '()' are also present. How can I remove them and replace them with their respective denotions? And last, the visual graph for this cannot be generated. It displays the error:

> This node either does not exist or has no visible connections. Check your Graph Settings if you expect such

That's the entire error.

But when I convert the objects from literal to IRI, it displays the data

[image]

and the graph is generated as well

[image]

I emailed the support team a week ago but they have not provided any response.

Comment: The converter is URL encoding the string you're using to create URI - reason: spaces are not valid chars in URIs

Comment: Can I do anything about this then? It also occurs with commas and parentheses

Comment: Hello, could you resent your email to graphdb-support@ontotext.com because I cannot find it?